# AWS Cloud Front Not Respecting TTL

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, cdn

We recently discovered that Cloudfront deletes files after 1 days regardless of minimum, maximum and default TTL settings in cloudFront or the origin headers.

Is there a way to override this header and force Cloudfront to respect TTL values?

If not, what TTL does Cloudfront really use before deleting files from CDN?

If there is really no SLA, any other reliable CDN with an SLA.

Request 1 HeadersResponse HIT

---

```
Response Version - HTTP/2
access-control-allow-origin 
*
age 
60847
alt-svc 
h3=":443"; ma=86400
cache-control   
max-age=2592000
content-encoding    
gzip
content-type    
text/css
date    
Sun, 30 Jul 2023 09:57:24 GMT
expires 
Tue, 29 Aug 2023 09:57:24 GMT
last-modified   
Wed, 20 Jan 1988 04:20:42 GMT
server  
nginx
vary    
Accept-Encoding
via 
1.1 xxx.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id XXX
x-amz-cf-pop    
YVR50-C1
x-cache 
Hit from cloudfront
```

Request 2 HeadersResponse MISS

---

````
Response Version - HTTP/2
access-control-allow-origin 
*
alt-svc 
h3=":443"; ma=86400
cache-control   
max-age=315360000
content-encoding    
gzip
content-type    
text/css
date    
Sun, 06 Aug 2023 00:12:08 GMT
expires 
Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
last-modified   
Wed, 20 Jan 1988 04:20:42 GMT
server  
nginx
vary    
Accept-Encoding
via 
1.1 xxx.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id 
x-amz-cf-id XXX
x-amz-cf-pop    
YVR50-C1
x-cache 
Miss from cloudfront ```
````

Answer (score 0):

After extensive discussions with Cloudfront support, it does appear that TTLs are merely suggestions. Cloudfront tries to respect them depending upon load on their resources etc. but no guarantees unless you have some sort of enterprise agreement with them.

I have moved some of the resources to Cloudflare and seen dramatic improvements.